# Xml doesn't save to file

Tags: c#, android, xml, xamarin, xamarin.android

I writing Android app in Xamarin

I have xml that is writing to file (realized)

On different Activity I try to open this file , replace some strings and save

Open file like this

```
var doc2 = new XmlDocument();
        var documentsPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
        var filePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(documentsPath, "myFile.xml");
        doc2.Load (filePath);
```

Replace some strings like this:

```
string str;
            str = doc2.OuterXml;

                str = str.Replace ("{ProductCode}", Code1);

            Console.WriteLine ("look");
            Console.WriteLine (str);

            doc2.Save (filePath);
            Console.WriteLine (doc2.OuterXml);
```

When I display str, I see that "ProductCode" changed.

But When  I display  "doc2.OuterXML" I see that it doesn't save.

This is "str":

```
  <Order CallConfirm="1" PayMethod="Безнал" QtyPerson="" Type="2" PayStateID="0" Remark="{Comment}" RemarkMoney="0" TimePlan="" Brand="1" DiscountPercent="0" BonusAmount="0" Department=""><Customer Login="" FIO="{FIO}" /><Address CityName="{CityName}" StationName="" StreetName="{StreetName}" House="{HouseName}" Corpus="" Building="" Flat="{FlatName}" Porch="" Floor="" DoorCode="" /><Phone Code="{Code}" Number="{Phone}" /><Products><Product Code="398" Qty="{QTY}" /><Product Code="{ProductCode1}" Qty="{QTY1}" /><Product Code="{ProductCode2}" Qty="{QTY2}" /></Products></Order>
```

This is doc2 after `doc2.Save (filePath);`:

```
<Order CallConfirm="1" PayMethod="Безнал" QtyPerson="" Type="2" PayStateID="0" Remark="{Comment}" RemarkMoney="0" TimePlan="" Brand="1" DiscountPercent="0" BonusAmount="0" Department=""><Customer Login="" FIO="{FIO}" /><Address CityName="{CityName}" StationName="" StreetName="{StreetName}" House="{HouseName}" Corpus="" Building="" Flat="{FlatName}" Porch="" Floor="" DoorCode="" /><Phone Code="{Code}" Number="{Phone}" /><Products><Product Code="{ProductCode}" Qty="{QTY}" /><Product Code="{ProductCode1}" Qty="{QTY1}" /><Product Code="{ProductCode2}" Qty="{QTY2}" /></Products></Order>
```

Why it doesn't save?

Comment: Please put more effort into formatting your code - and the XML. The code is all over the place at the moment, and each of your XML documents is on a single line...

Comment: You need to save the `str` back into `doc2`.  I.e. `doc2.OuterXml = str`.  Since c# strings are immutable, the `Replace` call returned a new string rather than modifying the original.  Though really I wouldn't do it this way at all, I would use the `XmlDocument` API itself to make the modification.

Comment: @dbc When I  write this I has this error .
 Error CS0200: Property or indexer 'System.Xml.XmlNode.OuterXml' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only

Comment: Ah, you probably want to use [`InnerXml`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.innerxml%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  Or don't do this at all, use `XDocument` below.  (Or use [`File.ReadAllText`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143368%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) then do string replace.  Why parse the XML at all if you're going to turn it back to a string immediately?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You haven't modified the document. You've asked the document for a string representation of itself, then assigned a new string to the same variable - but that doesn't change the XML in the document at all.

I would strongly urge you to use LINQ to XML (which is a nicer XML API) at which point you can have:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(filePath);
var query = doc.Descendants("Product")
               .Where(p => (string) p.Attribute("Code") == "{ProductCode}");
foreach (var element in query)
{
    element.SetAttributeValue("Code", Code1);
}
doc.Save(filePath);
```

Comment: Xamarin allow to use XDocument?

Comment: @Eugene: Yes, I'm sure it does.

Comment: @Eugene: Yes it is. You just need the right assembly references and using directives.

Comment: What assembly reference?

When I writing XDocument it change to XmlDocument

Comment: @Eugene: Well you need a using directive for System.Xml.Linq to start with... You may well find the assembly reference is already there.

Comment: Yes, I found this reference.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97178/discussion-between-eugene-and-jon-skeet).

Answer (score 0):

you have a missed a line

```
doc2.OuterXml = str;
```

Your code is that in the `OuterXml` is inside the `str`

```
string str;
str = doc2.OuterXml;
str = str.Replace ("{ProductCode}", Code1);
```

then you replaced the str values but not the doc2 value so it is unchanged. So now you need to add

```
string str;
str = doc2.OuterXml;
str = str.Replace ("{ProductCode}", Code1);

doc2.OuterXml = str;
```

and now you will see doc2.OuterXml will also gives you the same result.

Comment: I have an error when compile.  Error CS0200: Property or indexer 'System.Xml.XmlNode.OuterXml' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only